# How does rails parse html differently in input_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I have these 2 lines outputting a variable.

```
 <%= val %>   
 <%= v.input_field :value, value: val%>
```

but the output for the same thing is different.

```
<div>this is <strong style="text-decoration: underline;"> <span>underline</span></strong> now</div> 

<div>this is <strong>underline</strong> now</div>
```

what could be the reason same thing parsed differently? and possible solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By default rails escapes html in templates, if you want value of `val` to be rendered as-is - use `<%= val.html_safe %>` or `<%= raw val %>`, but beware of possible XSS.